# Does using the mid-point of a polygon always work in the Painter's HSR algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, computational-geometry

I'm referring to the painter's algorithm used in graphics here. I have some code in which I draw polygons from front to back using their mid point to judge how far away they are from the viewpoint. I am aware this will not work with overlapping polygons or polygons that intersect each-other, but will this work in all other cases? Will this work in cases where the polygons intersect each-other but only on one edge (such as the faces of a cube)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work in general, even if you restrict yourself to drawing convex polyhedra. For example, in 2D, take a look at this diagram:

[image: counterexample for 2d painter]

From the position of the eye (at the bottom of the diagram), the face A should be drawn before face B, since A is in front of B. But if you sort the faces based on the y-coordinate of their centers, then B comes before A.

This is a 2D counterexample, but the counterexample extends naturally to 3D.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.